# Several representations for key fingerprint

Tags: ssh, openssh, key-authentication, fingerprint

In `ssh` server and client authentication, key fingerprints are presented in different ways, even using the same command `ssh-keygen -lf` (in different hosts or as regards different keys).

**Representation 1**:

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
256 SHA256:3RE3UrGaTAec8H4YnZG7JTlfXpKvl89iexdqzLCyffY root@hostname1 (ED25519)
```

**Representation 2**:

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
d0:21:3e:ec:52:ff:19:a9:e7:71:b5:7f:63:23:57:f7
```

(example from [this page](https://pubs.vmware.com/nsxt-11/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.nsxt.admin.doc%2FGUID-8F3D860E-4F01-452E-A54D-A45FF455F8EB.html))

**Representation 3**:

```
AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBHVo5+sYnRQxerJjG/DmUzQFso+CGzcnGT/SDa457qQqh6WIquvWOIXIY5gNPZoOByAoriK+WRxgTT39hYFmpXE=
```

from

```
$ ssh-keygen -H -F hostname2
|1|/DmY6Hm8TdZogykndJOUacp2NaM=|uM+t3vLw3KRySPUeXNqBLCxaGtY= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBHVo5+sYnRQxerJjG/DmUzQFso+CGzcnGT/SDa457qQqh6WIquvWOIXIY5gNPZoOByAoriK+WRxgTT39hYFmpXE=
```

which is the line in `.ssh/known_hosts` file corresponding to `hostname2`.

What is the difference between them? And, if they are equivalent, how to get each representation from the other ones?

---

Representations 1 and 3 have been obtained using `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017` on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Representation 3 is base64. `echo` that string into `base64 -d | xxd`

Comment: @Panki Including the beginning `AAAA`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of the [`ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen) utility from OpenSSH displayed only MD5 hashes; the utility [now defaults to displaying a SHA256 hash](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/ssh-keygen.c?rev=1.251&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup), although you can still select an MD5 hash using the `-E` option:

```
user@host:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -E md5 -l -f samplekey
2048 MD5:e6:1f:73:0f:14:cb:9a:71:2f:3b:31:b7:3f:58:1c:52 user@host (RSA)
user@host:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -E sha256 -l -f samplekey
2048 SHA256:Oyt9H15ZBmITbhljpSiE/BLreo/+j+6lsC3gClGI97U user@host (RSA)
user@host:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -B -l -f samplekey
2048 xomiz-lozad-ruzin-lasuz-vibic-fydar-hecoh-mapuv-vytus-futah-maxox user@host (RSA)
```

In addition, you can add the `-v` (visual) flag on either the MD5 or SHA256 hash to get an ascii-art comparison image in addition to an alphanumeric hash:

```
user@host:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -E sha256 -l -v -f samplekey
2048 SHA256:Oyt9H15ZBmITbhljpSiE/BLreo/+j+6lsC3gClGI97U user@host (RSA)
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|     . ..   =..  |
|..    +.   + *   |
|o o   .+. . O .  |
| o . .o... o o . |
|.   ..E.S       o|
| .  . .  .     + |
|.  . o..o . . o  |
| .  o +=.*.. o   |
|  .. o+BXo..o    |
+----[SHA256]-----+
user@host:~/.ssh$
```

---

Your third representation is not a fingerprint, but the public key, base-64 encoded, as it will be stored in a `samplekey.pub` file or in the `known_hosts` file on a system accepting that key.

There is no way to determine the key from the hash; to obtain the hash from the key, use the `ssh-keygen` utility either with its default options, or using the `-E`, `-B`, and/or `-v` options to get the output style you prefer.

To obtain the fingerprint of a key in a `known_hosts` file (rather than in the original public key file, as per examples above), you could pipe a string containing the key-type and the key directly to `ssh-keygen`:

```
$ echo "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBHVo5+sYnRQxerJjG/DmUzQFso+CGzcnGT/SDa457qQqh6WIquvWOIXIY5gNPZoOByAoriK+WRxgTT39hYFmpXE=" | ssh-keygen -l -f -
256 SHA256:wOxOBgRQp1qQcnTIjgmE/GB8+3fm8ahyDXuL/2GzgIo no comment (ECDSA)
```

Comment: A massive *thank you* for such a detailed information.